# Is there a way to return all unrefrenced objects?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have this "Linked Web"(?) data structure
ie. each object has a bunch of references to other objects.

So i wrote a method that is supposed to 'remove' a passed object by removing all references to it.

I need to test it and make sure that after i run the method the particular object i want to remove is not referenced by anything else

How could I do this?

An idea would be to force a Garbage Collection then run my delete object method and then force another GC to see if it found an object.

if it found an object for deletion then I would assume that my method works
but if it found nothing to collect then I would assume that something is referencing it and would have to plug that leak

Is this possible? How?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep track of each object via a [`WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) and check the `IsAlive` property after a garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

This strikes me as an overly convoluted way to test whether your logic is correct. I would construct a couple of unit tests in the following manner.

1. Add an object to the web. In the test keep a reference to the object
2. Call the logic that unhooks the reference from the web.
3. Iterate over (or traverse) your web and use the [ObjectReferenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183759.aspx) to see if the reference you're looking for is still hanging around.Since you have numerous possible connections, this may not be the swiftest of operations. However in a relatively small test it should be fine.

There is nothing in your scenario that leads me to believe you need to leverage garbage collection to test your data structure. Also, I believe your data structure is correctly termed a graph. Good luck